# HMENU in TYPO3 Typoscript

Tags: menu, typo3, typoscript

I have a project which has multiple websites. Please check the screen shot. 
 [image]

Now, I want to build a menu in "Red", which will contain "Blue", "Post" and "Blog Page" websites. And each tab, that is Blue, Post and Blog Post should display the pages in their websites.

Example:

```
Red Menu
-Blue
 --jQueryTestPage
 --Home
 --Fluid
 --Contact
 --Form
-Post
 --HomePage
 --Contact Us
-Blog Page
 --Startsite
 --Sitemap
```

I'm very new to Typo3 and I'm unable to understand how to create menus for these pages. I am using Typo3 6.0.4

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE**

So far I have the following typoscript code for the menu

```
lib.mainMenu = HMENU
lib.mainMenu.entryLevel=0
lib.mainMenu.special=list
lib.mainMenu.special.value=19,5,2
lib.mainMenu.1 = TMENU
lib.mainMenu.1 {
  wrap = <ul id="mainMenu">|</ul>
  expAll = 0
  NO.allWrap = <li class="mainMenuiItem">|</li>
  RO < .NO
  RO = 1
  CUR < .NO
  CUR = 1
  CUR.allWrap = <li class="mainMenuItemActive">|</li>
  ACT < .CUR
}
```

The above code gives me

```
Red Menu
    -Blue
    -Post
    -Blog Page
```

But I want is

```
Red Menu
    -Blue
     --jQueryTestPage
     --Home
     --Fluid
     --Contact
     --Form
    -Post
     --HomePage
     --Contact Us
    -Blog Page
     --Startsite
     --Sitemap
```

Answer (score 3):

lib.mainMenu.1 means first level. So add additional levels:

```
lib.mainMenu.2 < lib.mainMenu.1
lib.mainMenu.3 < lib.mainMenu.1
```

But afaik you need to use "directory" instead of "list". "list" just renders the pages and not the subpages.

And remove entryLevel=0 - if you use special, you should not use entryLevel.

```
lib.mainMenu = HMENU
lib.mainMenu {
  special=directory
  special.value=19,5,2
  1 = TMENU
  1 {
    wrap = <ul id="mainMenu">|</ul>
    expAll = 0
    NO.allWrap = <li class="mainMenuiItem">|</li>
    # afaik you do not need RO
    RO < .NO
    RO = 1
    CUR < .NO
    CUR = 1
    CUR.allWrap = <li class="mainMenuItemActive">|</li>
    ACT < .CUR
  }
  2 < .1
  2 {
    wrap = <ul>|</ul>
    NO.allWrap = ...
    CUR.allWrap = ...
  }
  3 < .2
}
```

Comment: Great.Thanks. This works. But there is again one issue. 
Now, only the subpages are getting displayed. The main pages that are "Blue", "Post" etc are not displaying.

Comment: "list" shows only the parent pages and not the child pages.
"directory" shows only the child pages and not the parent pages.

Answer (score 1):

As you're hardcoding the values anyway, you can use special=directory and put in the parent page items manually.

```
lib.completeMenu = COA
lib.completeMenu {
  10 = TEXT
  ...
  # Make Typolink to page 19
  }
  20 = HMENU
  20 {
     special=directory
     special.value=19
     ...
     # Your menu, just for the first part
  }
  30 < .10
  30.value = ... 
  # The next typolink to page 5
  40 < .20
  40.special.value = 5
  ... 
  # your menu, for the second part
  # repeat this for all the desired steps
}
```

To avoid writing the same ID multiple times, you can use constants like {$blueRootPage}

PS: above TS is untested